# Size of External Library

Tags: android, gradle, jar, sdk, gson

I'm developing an SDK which uses GSON (JAR size is 180 KB), even after adding it, the size of final aar generated is 111 KB. Why does the final size is less than GSON JAR file?

Answer (score 0):

Both aar and jar are zip files, which follow additional conventions. Zip files can be compressed. I'd guess that the original jar is not compressed, while the aar is compressed.